# Spomkylabs Jose PHP

Tags: php, jwe, jose

I need to decrypt my cipherText using the content encryption key + IV and validate it against the AAD and tag using A128CBC-HS256. I have found this [library](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose/blob/master/src/Algorithm/ContentEncryption/AESCBCHS.php) doing this. But, I do i use it? I have searched for other jwe libraries, but they only decrypt the ciphertext without validating with the aad and tag.

I have tried implementing the library but i've encountered errors and the documentation isn't helpful for novices like me.

I have also tried php's openssl_decrypt, but it is only for GCM and CCM, not CBC.

Comment: 2 upvotes for this question. You must have alot of friends here in SO :)

Comment: Why don’t you ask directly [here](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose/issues)? I will be happy to help you